# What is the difference between the peek() and top() function in the stack?

Tags: c++, c++14

I am using the stack and using peek and and top functions but I can not get any difference between them.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by "using the stack" - do you mean `std::stack`?

Comment: `std::stack` does not have a `peek()` method.

Answer (score 9):

The difference between them is that [`std::stack::top()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack/top) is in the standard and that `std::stack::peek()` is not.

Maybe you are using some custom stack type that derives from `std::stack` somehow that adds `peek()` as a member function? In that case I would expect both functions to behave exactly the same.

Comment: It might be of value to mention that pop is often (not in std::stack::pop) defined as returning the top value as well as discarding it from the stack. Hence the need for a peek.

Answer (score 1):

**peek()** & **top()** functions are same but **peek()** is unavailable in `std::stack`. You can check it here- http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stack/stack/ . Actually, **peek()** and **top()** both take **O(1)** time without any other queries.

Comment: That does not really answer the question.

Comment: @t.niese, Updated my answer.